# Meaning of 'be careful of too many too fast'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> But I know that makes no difference to you because you’re 80 years old and you don't care if you think you will be a hero no matter what, and I am not interested in you, what will it do to this court? You will destroy it. And I am thinking that. And I am really thinking it. And there we are. … There’s a lot in here about the court and how it should function and it would be weird of drawing too many generalizations. I’ll start with the one that you started with. I think that's this is a pretty bad situation here. And it proved to be such. For a lot of complex reasons. And lessons, there must be lessons. **Be careful of too many too fast**. And believe in the obvious. But it has kept us, at least the judges, in this room, absolutely fascinated for three hours and 10 minutes because of the quality of the argument in part, and because the the nature of the materials, and because of the kinds of problems that have been posed.

Notice that the transcript below [the video](http://www.c-span.org/video/?197515-1/reconsideration-dred-scott-v-sandford) doesn't transcribe Justice Breyer's words 100% correctly.

Answer (score 3):

"Too many, too fast" is an [idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom) similar to, "Too little, too late."

This particular idiom describes the situation in which something is rushed to the point of not being effective. This is why the addressee must be careful of it.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard "too many, too fast" as an idiom like "too little, too late".

I would therefore think that it refers to the sentence just in front of it: "And lessons, there must be lessons. Be careful of too many too fast." translated as:

> And thinking of lessons: Yes, there must be lessons. But be careful. There mustn't be too many lessons too fast.